# How do I set up a GA4 conversion event based on a confirmation page and a specific page preceding it?

Tags: google-analytics-4

In Universal Analytics, I could set up a goal based on a confirmation and that a specific URL preceded it. But I can't figure out how to do this in GA4.
Confirmation page contains: confirmation/demo
Preceding page contains: book-demo

Any ideas?

I tried adding an event like I would add a goal in Universal Analytics. I don't see an option for setting up a prior step in the funnel.